# How do I check the BIOS version number on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, bios

On Linux I would do something like `dmidecode -s bios-version` as root.

What is the equivalent for OpenBSD?

Comment: I dont' know openBSD however freeBSD knows dmidecode : https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dmidecode&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html. Ha ! Just checked and it seems openBSD knows it as well. https://openports.se/sysutils/dmidecode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as `root`,

```
pkg_add dmidecode
# if not done so already
printf "kern.allowkmem=1\n" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
reboot
```

and then again as `root`

```
dmidecode -s bios-version
```

Comment: And then revert `allowkmem`, by removing the respective line on `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and reboot again.

Answer (score 1):

Often, `dmesg` is enough:

```
$ dmesg | grep ^bios0
bios0 at mainbus0: SMBIOS rev. 3.0 @ 0xa728d000 (91 entries)
bios0: vendor American Megatrends Inc. version "1205" date 05/03/2018
bios0: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. PRIME H270-PRO
```

The second line is the relevant one, in this case: the machine has BIOS version 1205.